# Compact way to test for "not null" and set a value accordingly in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

This of course fails if "x" is null:

```
var x = document.getElementById('myElem');
x.value = "Hello";
```

Sure enough, we should always check if a pointer points to something :)

```
var x = document.getElementById('myElem');
if (x)
  x.value = "Hello";
```

Now, is there a way in plain JS or even jQuery (I must load it anyway, so...) to do something like

```
setIfExists('myElem', 'Hello');
```

Yes, I can write

```
function setIfExists(el, v) {
  var x = document.getElementById(el);
  if (x)
    x.value = v;
}
```

But I would like to know if such a function exists already. Thank you

Comment: You've tagged this with `jquery` and that's indeed the answer. Why not just use `$("#myElem").val("Hello")`?

Comment: `x && (x.value = "hello")`

Comment: I do not know jQuery at all, so, all help is welcome :)

Comment: I found the question legitimate. In C#, for example, one who doesn't know about  null-coalescing operator or LYNQ write some code asking how to make it compact. SQL questions are often the same: is there a better way to do that?

Comment: _"I do not know jQuery at all"_ -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: @Andreas sure, you cannot find anybody more willing to learn than me, but I cannot spend weeks trying to learn a whole library (which everybody is saying is useless if you can rely on the latest JS versions btw) just to find a small answer :) But thanks for the link

Comment: So your time is more valuable than ours? That's good to know... And that one-liner from the accepted answer would have been a matter of some minutes to an hour to find/learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So yes, the aim of Jquery : write less, do more

```
$("#myElem").val("Hello")
```

That's the least you could ever find in all method that ever exist.

Answer (score 1):

Pick your poison here

```js
// fake it with new object if it is not there but creates an object
var y = document.getElementById('myElem') || {};
console.log(y); //logs {}
y.value = "Hello";
console.log(y); //logs {"value":"Hello"}

//jQuery, produce no error, logs undefined, c is 
//jQuery object that gets nothing assigned since 
//element does not exist so it is undefined
let c = $("#myElem").val("Cheers");
console.log(typeof c); // logs object 
console.log(c instanceof jQuery); // logs true
//console.log(c);// logs jQuery
console.log(c.jquery); // logs jQuery version "3.3.1"
console.log(c.val()); //undefined

let notthere = $("#myElem");
notthere.length || notthere.val("Howdy");
console.log(notthere.value); // undefined

// get the value only
let j = $("#myElem").value = "Woot";
console.log(typeof j, "j:", j); // string j: Woot
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the analysis of all the possible cases :)